# Matrix not applying to pose bone correctly

Tags: python, animation, import, pose-mode, matrix

I'm attempting to import animations from text files but I can't seem to figure out how to properly import it. If I make a list of positions in a text file like here

```
from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion, Matrix, Euler
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1) 
M1 = Matrix.Translation(Vector((0, 0, 0)))
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[0].matrix = M1
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[0].keyframe_insert('location')
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[0].keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion') 
M2 = Matrix.Translation(Vector((0, 0, 2))) 
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[1].matrix = M2
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[1].keyframe_insert('location')
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[1].keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion')  
M3 = Matrix.Translation(Vector((0, 2, 4)))
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[2].matrix = M3
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[2].keyframe_insert('location')
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[2].keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion')
```

https://pastebin.com/HRp8pbTn

Full code I type in to console in the pastebin. Typing that gets me the animation as I exported with no issues that I can see. If I write a loop for it however like so

```
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'POSE')
    for frame in range(transform_count):
        current_frame = frame + 1
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(current_frame)
        for node in node_list:
            node_rotation = processed_file[frame_index + node_index + 7].split()
            node_translation = processed_file[frame_index + node_index + 8].split()
            node_scale = processed_file[frame_index + node_index + 9]
            matrix_translation = Matrix.Translation(Vector((float(node_translation[0]), float(node_translation[1]), float(node_translation[2]))))
            matrix_rotation = Quaternion((float(node_rotation[3]), float(node_rotation[0]), float(node_rotation[1]), float(node_rotation[2]))).inverted().to_matrix().to_4x4()
            full_matrix =  matrix_translation @ matrix_rotation
            armature.pose.bones[node].matrix = full_matrix
            armature.pose.bones[node].keyframe_insert('location')
            armature.pose.bones[node].keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion')
            frame_index += 3

        frame_set += 1
```

The position of the bones are all wrong. It's almost like the matrix is either being ignored or it's taking the matrix I give it and adding it the the pose bones current position. I want it to be exactly at the matrix I give it which is a global matrix. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Added

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

right after setting the matrix. That fixed my issue.